# How to get Power! and ????? achievements in Atomas?

Tags: achievements, atomas

I can't find any info about this game anywhere and really want to get these achievements. I'm not sure what they are just yet but if I could figure out it would be much appreciated. Again the names of the achievements are called, Power!, And ??????????